# which one is more efficient way to add attributes to text box in c#, at aspx page while designing or at code behind file?

Tags: c#

Which one is the more efficient way to add attributes to text box in c#, in the .aspx page while designing or in the code behind  file?

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

.aspx file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onfocus="this.select();">
```

.aspx.cs file:

```
txt1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.select();");
```

Which one is the better and more efficient way?

Comment: which one is more efficient way to add attributes to text box in c#, at aspx page while designing or at code behind  file?

FOR EXAMPLE 
in .aspx file

**asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onfocus="this.select();"**

in aspx.cs file
**txt1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.select();");**

which one is better and more efficient way?

Comment: what do you mean by "efficient"?